# Is it true that $\dim(X) \leq \dim(X^{\ast})$ for every infinite dimentional Banach space $X$?

Tags: banach-spaces, cardinals

Given an arbitrary infinite dimensional Banach space $X$, can we deduce that it's dimension $\dim(X)$ (the cardinality of one of its Hamel bases) is less or equal of the dimension  $\dim(X^{\ast})$ of its dual space (the space of all continuous linear functionals $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question which  has been unaddressed for a long time, so I'll give it a shot.

Lets denote the cardinality of a set $A$
by $|A|$. For a normed space $X$ we define its *density
character* $d(X)$ as the smallest cardinality of its dense sets, that
is $d(X)=\min\{|D|: D\subseteq X, \overline{D}=X\}$. In particular a separable normed space $X$ has $d(X)=\aleph_0$.

We need the following three lemmas:

> **Lemma 1:** If $X$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and
>   $\dim X\geq |\mathbb{R}|$, then $\dim X=|X|$.

A proof of Lemma 1 can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541096/cardinality-of-a-vector-space-versus-the-cardinality-of-its-basis).

> **Lemma 2:** 
>   Let $X$, $Y$ be infinite dimensional Banach spaces with $d(X)\leq
> d(Y)$. Then $|X|\leq |Y|.$

You can find a proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72750/density-character-and-cardinality).

For the last step, it is known from functional analysis that when
$X^*$ is separable, then so is $X$. If you check  the proof carefully you'll realise that    what is actually proven is the following:

> **Lemma 3:** Let $X$ be a normed space. Then $d(X)\leq d(X^*)$.
>
> **Proof.**
>   Let $\{x_a^*: a\in A\}$ be  a dense subset of $S_{X^*}$ of
>   cardinality $|A|=d(X^*)$. For every $a\in A$ we pick an $x_a\in B_X$
>   with $x_a^*(x_a)>\tfrac{1}{2}$ and set $Y= \langle \{x_a: a\in A\} \rangle$.
>   The set $Y$ is dense in $X$: Otherwise, there would exist an $f \in
> X^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ such that $f(y)=0$ for every $y\in Y$. But then
>   for every $a\in A$,
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> \|f-x_a^*\|\geq |f(x_a)-x_a^*(x_a)|=\frac{1}{2},
> \end{eqnarray*}
>   which implies that $f\notin \overline{\{x_a^*: a\in A\}}=S_{X^*}$, a
>   contradiction. So $X$ contains a dense subset of cardinality
>   $|Y|\leq |A|$, therefore $d(X)\leq |A|=d(X^*)$.

Combining the previous lemmas, we get an affirmative answer to remilt's question.

Comment: Nice! Thank you tree detective, it's been two years since I have made this question and had completely forgot it since it never got much attention!

Comment: Just to confirm, does this argument use Hahn-Banach?

Comment: @MichaelGaudreau Yes, the existence of an $f$ with norm one that vanishes on $\overline{Y}$ in the proof of Lemma 3, is a consequence of the Hahn Banach theorem.

Answer (score 2):

That is a great answer to a very interesting problem. Given your current solution, I would like to suggest a possible generalization to the case of normed spaces.

Since in the finite dimensional case everything is working well, let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space and consider the canonical embedding of $X$ to its double dual $X^{**}$ given by:

$T:X\rightarrow X^{**},\hspace{10pt}  T(x)=T_x \hspace{5pt}$ where for $x\in X,$ we define $T_x:X^*\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $ \hspace{7pt}  {T_x}(x^*)=x^*(x)$

Of course, T is an isometric embedding.

Consider the spaces:

$T(X)\hspace{5pt}$ (which is isometric to $X$ and obviously dense in $\overline{T(X)}$) and

$\overline{T(X)}\hspace{5pt}$ (which is a Banach space, as it is a closed subspace of the Banach space $X^{**}$)

(This process is of course standard when considering the completion of a normed space $X$).

Since $\overline{T(X)}$ is a Banach space, by your argument we must have that $\dim(\overline{T(X)})\leq \dim(({\overline{T(X)}})^*)$

But, since $T(X)$ is dense in $\overline{T(X)},$ we must have that the spaces ${(T(X))}^*$ and $({\overline{T(X)}})^*$ are isometric.

(Indeed, consider this result when stated in the following more general fashion:

Let $X$ be a normed space, $Z$ a dense subspace of $X$ and $Y$ a Banach space. Then, the spaces $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ and $\mathcal{B}(Z,Y)$ are isometric.

I will be glad to give hints to the proof of this fact, if anyone is interested).

Now combine all the previous arguments together to get:

$\dim(X)= \dim(T(X))\leq \dim({\overline{T(X)}})\leq \dim(({\overline{T(X)}})^*) = \dim(({T(X)})^*)= \dim(X^*)$

(Notice that we have also implicitly used the fact that if two spaces are isometric, then their duals must be isometric as well).

Comment: Wow! Suddenly a lot of motion around this old question. Now I wonder if we have a space with dimension strictly smaller than its dual, and we consider its orbit when * acts on it. Does there exists such a space, for which the dimension finally becomes constant? If yes when we end up with a reflexive space or even with a self dual space?

Comment: If you could end  up with a reflexive space, this would imply that your original space would be reflexive as well (and actually the whole sequence $X, X^*, X^{**}\ldots$), since a Banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual is reflexive. This would contradict  the fact that $\dim X< \dim X^*$. But the question is still valid, I mean whether the dimension can become constant. The only example of a space $X$ with $\dim X <\dim X^*$ that I know of, is $X=\ell_\infty$, but the dimension of the sequence of the duals is strictly increasing.

Comment: Sorry I guess I have ages to even touch Functional analysis. Can't we have $\dim X<\dim X^*=\dim X^{**}=\dim X^{***}=\dim X^{****}$ with $X^*=X^{***}$, and $X^{**}=X^{****}$? I mean we may have $X$ not even a pre-dual no? Also do you have a reference about the fact that the sequence of the duals of $l_{\infty}$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: All I am saying is that none of these spaces can be reflexive, provided that $X$ is a Banach space. But they may end up to be isomorphic, or even isometrically isomorphic, I can't rule out this possibility. I guess that by equality you mean the latter. If $X$ is not reflexive you can end up with a reflexive space of course (for example, $X=(c_{00}, \|\cdot\|_p)$. By the way, reading  your first comment, I started to wonder whether  a self dual space is reflexive. Is  this true? I haven't managed to show it.

Comment: About the duals of $\ell_\infty$ I wasn't exactly correct. To be more precise the sequence $\ell_\infty, \ell_\infty^{**}, \ell_\infty^{****}, \ldots,$ has strictly increasing dimensions by Theorem 2.1 of Rosenthal's paper: https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/Material/injective.pdf    
If $\Delta $ is a set, then $\ell_\infty(\Delta)^{**} \simeq \ell_\infty(\Gamma)$, where $\Gamma$ is a set of cardinality $|\Gamma|=2^{\dim \ell_\infty(\Delta)}$. The same theorem also describes  $\ell_\infty(\Delta)^*$, but I can't say for sure whether its dimension lies strictly in between.

Comment: Well, a density argument shows that for $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$,  $\textrm{dens}( \ell_\infty^{*}) =2^c> c=\dim \ell_\infty $, so there is hope for the odd "powers" after all.

Comment: And to answer  my own question, I think an example of a self-dual space which is not reflexive is  $X=J\oplus J^*$, (where $J$ is the James space, a non-reflexive space isometric to its second dual).