# It is still true that $\dim X \le \dim X^\star$ for infinite-dimensional Banach spaces if $\dim X < 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and $E^\star$ its topological dual. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2001928/1019043) answer, @tree detective showed that if $\dim X \ge 2^{\aleph_0}$, then $\dim X \le \dim X^\star$.

Does the result hold if we remove the assumption $\dim X \ge 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\dim X < 2^{\aleph_0}$? That it has a countable basis?

Comment: @Meowdog It depends on if you assume continuum hypothesis (CH). By AC, any $2$ cardinalities are comparable, so I guess writing $\dim X < 2^{\aleph_0}$ makes sense even we do not assume CH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Banach space $X$ of dimension less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ must be finite-dimensional, in which case case $\dim X = \dim X^*$.

> H.E. Lacey, [The Hamel Dimension of any Infinite Dimensional Separable Banach Space is c](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318458), *Amer. Math. Mon.* **80** (1973), 298.

Comment: May I ask for the reason of a downvote?

Comment: So you really want a user to suggest why a post is downvoted (not by me), but if you tell them, you'll provide just say: You're wrong and I'm right.  That's a good argument for users never to comment on their downvotes, And you please stop asking "Why".

Comment: @amWhy, sorry, I am not interested in being the maths police here. This is a valid question.

Comment: Agree with @TomaszKania that it's a valid question. Even if the downvoter themselves does not answer, the community may suggest potential reasons or improvements to avoid further downvotes. To me this is a great succinct answer (+1), although other users may think of it as a "link-only" answer.