# If two infinite vector spaces have the same cardinality then they are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field. Suppose that $V,W$ are $F$-vector spaces with infinite cardinality. Is it true that they have the same dimension?

If it is not true, will it be true if $|V|,|W| \geq |F|$?

Comment: Note $\text{dim}_{\Bbb{R}}\Bbb{R}=1$, whereas  $\text{dim}_{\Bbb{R}}\Bbb{C}=2$. So not isomorphic over the scalar field $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @AnuragA, how can I forget about this simple example... Thank you!

Comment: What am I missing here? Why isn't the answer to this "no because $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ have infinite cardinality, but not the same dimension"?

Comment: @AnuragA Would you mind taking a look at my comment above please?

Comment: @Ovi of course your example works perfectly.

Comment: @AnuragA, is it true that any infinite vector spaces can be embedded into an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: @AnuragA, moreover, regarding my original question: If $|V|=|W| \geq |F|$, is it true that they have the same dimension?

Comment: @bbw $| \mathbb{R}^2 |= |\mathbb{R}^3| = | \mathbb{R}|$

Comment: @AnuragA Okay thanks

Comment: @Ovi, thank you!

Comment: @bbw Sure! ${}{}$

Comment: You may find this question interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541096/cardinality-of-a-vector-space-versus-the-cardinality-of-its-basis

Comment: @LucaCarai, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As they told you in the comments, that is not true even assuming $|V|=|W| \geq |F|$. Indeed, $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}^2|\geq |\mathbb{R}|$ but $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces.

But if you assume $|V|=|W| > |F|$ then it is true.

For every non-zero $F$-vector space $V$ we have that 
$$\max \{|F|, \mbox{dim}_{F}V \} \le |V| \le \max \{ \aleph_0, |F|, \mbox{dim}_{F}V \}$$
(see the answer in [Cardinality of a vector space versus the cardinality of its basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541096/cardinality-of-a-vector-space-versus-the-cardinality-of-its-basis)).

If $|V|=|W|=1$, the claim is clearly true. Thus we can assume $V$ and $W$ to be non-zero. If $F$ is finite, then either $|V|=|W|$ is at most countable and it is easy to show that this implies $\mbox{dim}_{F}V=\mbox{dim}_{F}W$ or $|V|=|W|$ is uncountable and then $\mbox{dim}_{F}V=|V|=|W|= \mbox{dim}_{F}W$. If $F$ is infinite, then $|F| \geq \mbox{dim}_{F}V$ cannot happen because we would have $|V|=|W|=|F|$. If $F$ is infinite and $|F| < \mbox{dim}_{F}V$, then $\mbox{dim}_{F}V=|V|=|W|= \mbox{dim}_{F}W$.

In either case we have $\mbox{dim}_{F}V= \mbox{dim}_{F}W$. So $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you. But if this is true, I have another question. Given a field $F$, does there exists a $F$-vector space $V$ such that $|V|>|F|$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Take the free $F$-vector space on a set of cardinality strictly bigger than $|F|$. In this way, you can find vector spaces of arbitrarily large cardinality.

Comment: What do you mean by the "the free $F$-vector space"? My thought was, if $F$ is finite, then any infinite $F$-vector space will do. If $F$ is infinite, then $|F|$ is of the form $\aleph_{\alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. Then, for example, any set of cardinality $\aleph_{\beta}$ for $\beta > \alpha$ is bigger then $|F|$. But this is just a set, how can I get a vector space bigger than $|F|$?

Comment: For the definition of free $F$-vector space see this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module. Take the ring $R$ to be the field $F$. The free vector space on a set $X$ is a vector space with dimension $|X|$.