# How to prove that if $\dim E=\infty$, then $|E|=\dim E$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector space with cardinality $|E|$. $\dim E$ is the cardinality of a Hamel basis of $E$. Suppose that $\dim E$ is infinite. How to prove that $|E|=\dim E$?

The situation where $E$ is a Banach space is already tackled in [this paper](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/hamel.pdf). Another [paper in German](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm5/sm513.pdf) seems to answer the question for linear spaces in general, but I cannot read it.

If the statement is not true for general vector spaces, can anyone offer a counterexample?

**To clarify,**

1. By "=", I mean the cardinalities are equal.
2. Maybe some topological properties such as completeness should be assumed to get some results.

Comment: So it suffices to show $|E|= \infty$?  But $\dim E = \infty$ clearly implies that $E$ contains infinitely many points...

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541096/19542).

Comment: Needs clarification.  For a real vector space, we could have $\dim E = \aleph_0$ but $|E| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.  So either you will need to specify a countable field, or else take the cardinal of the field into account. Indeed, in that Löwig paper for real vector spaces, Satz 2 says: if $0<\dim E < \mathfrak c$ then $|E| = \mathfrak c$ and if $\dim E \ge \mathfrak c$ then $|E| = \dim E$.

Comment: @Eric: The question doesn't make sense *outside* of Banach spaces. It mentions topological completeness, and generally speaking it's false since $\dim\Bbb R[x]=\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The question is explicitly _not_ about Banach spaces since OP says they already know the answer in that case, and I suspect they are unaware of the example of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.